# Merging objects of an array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to merge all objects together using lodash and I tried _.assign and _.merge still it shows the objects separately.

```
 var arr = [
    {"asf" : 33, "ff1" : 12},{"xx" : 90, "ff2" : 13},{"xw" : 66, "ff3" : 176}
]
  console.log( _.assign({}, arr)); //should show {"asf" : 33, "ff1" : 12,"xx" : 90, "ff2" : 13, "xw" : 66, "ff3" : 176}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymppagdq/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
_.assign.apply(_, arr);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymppagdq/2/

or `_.reduce(arr, _.extend)` would also work.

Answer (score 9):

In ES2015, you can use `_.assign(...arr)`, or if you're really only targeting ES2015, `Object.assign(...arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a method which accepts an array of objects, apply can be used to call with multiple arguments:

```
var arr = [...];
_.assign.apply(_, [{}].concat(arr))
```